# How to draw on Gtk.Image?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I want to draw something on a Gtk.Image widget. The problem is that my drawing must be drawn on top of an original picture. I've tried doing this:

```py
image.connect('draw', self.__on_image_draw)
...
def __on_image_draw(self, widget, g):
    widget.draw(g)
    if self.__in_crop_mode:
        g.set_source_rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        g.set_line_width(2)
        g.rectangle(10, 10, 200, 200)
        g.stroke()
    return True
```

Unfortunately the call to widget.draw() crashes my program. :P

How can I draw something on top of the picture in the Gtk.Image widget?

Comment: `widget.draw(g)` emits the 'draw' signal again and eventually the program crashes.

Comment: Yes, but how to draw image and then draw rectangle on top of image?

Answer (score 0):

Using `widget.draw` causes the signal to be fired, which calls your function which signals....  To stop this from happening, you need to disconnect the signal before calling draw.  I think you need to call __on_image_draw only once, which means you can add this above your call to draw: `widget.disconnect_by_func(__on_image_draw)`